# Dlib training for kids database

Tags: python, training-data, dlib

I'm trying to train an Face detector using Dlib. I selected close to 1000 images for training. As per the documentation, i have created `training_with_face_landmarks.xml`  using that images. But, i don't understand,

- What are the images used for `testing_with_face_landmarks.xml` file?
- Both `training_with_face_landmarks.xml` and `testing_with_face_landmarks.xml` files use same images?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: those are the test images you want to see, if your results are passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [dlib](http://dlib.net/faq.html#WhydoesnttheobjectdetectorItrainedwork) reference:

> - **Using training images that don't look like the testing images**
>
> This should be obvious, but needs to be pointed out. If there is some
>   clear difference between your training and testing images then you
>   have messed up. You need to show the training algorithm real images so
>   it can learn what to do. If instead you only show it images that look
>   obviously different from your testing images don't be surprised if,
>   when you run the detector on the testing images, it doesn't work. As a
>   rule of thumb, a human should not be able to tell if an image came
>   from the training dataset or testing dataset.
>
> Here are some examples of bad datasets:
>
> - A training dataset where objects always appear with some specific orientation but the testing images have a diverse set of orientations.
> - A training dataset where objects are tightly cropped, but testing images that are uncropped.
> - A training dataset where objects appear only on a perfectly white background with nothing else present, but testing images where objects
>     appear in a normal environment like living rooms or in natural scenes.

So, don't use that images, which is used in training. Use different images for testing.